# android : ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug'. > java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../support/v7/recyclerview (Is a directory)

Tags: java, android

I implemented Two classes for tabs Name `SlidingTabLayout` and `SlidingTabStrip` some of you may be familiar with in old project it is working fine but in new project it gives me this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for 
task:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug'.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/7C88771C8876D45C/Android 
 Workplace/Tablayout/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug
 /android/support/v7/recyclerview (Is a directory)
```

When using compile time *dependency*

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

Comment: have you include RecyclerView library in your project?

Comment: i did already after that giving me this error Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
> Unable to delete directory: /mnt/7C88771C8876D45C/Android Workplace/Tablayout/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/jars

Answer (score 0):

make sure you include librairy Recyclerview in your build.graddle file if you use android-studio or jar of Recyclerview in eclipse